# Need to pass Model obejct with form data while upload file from Jquery to Controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

I am try to upload files, need to pass files  from ajax call to controller,but issue is i need to pass files along with model object ,which is creating issue.
Please find the code as below:

```
//Step 1: All uploaded files
var files = $("#postedFile").get(0).files;
var fdata = new FormData();
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  fdata.append("files", files[i]);
};


//Step 2: Serialized form 
var ModelObject = $('#form').serializeObject();

//Step 3: Ajax call:
$.ajax({
  url: '/controller/actionname',
  data: fdata,
  dataType: "json",
  async: false,
  type: 'post',
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  success: function(response) {

  },

  error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, error) {
    emailStatus = false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Please share action parameters code.

Answer (score 1):

First, use ajax to replace the original form submission method, you need to add **`event.preventDefault();`** to the click event to prevent the default form submission method from occurring.

> I am try to upload files, need to pass files from ajax call to
> controller,but issue is i need to pass files along with model object
> ,which is creating issue.

To solve it, you can use the following **two methods** to pass parameters by ajax:

1. Use `var fdata = new FormData($('#form').get(0));`  to get all the
   model data in the form.
2. Split the ModelObject as an array and then take fields by name and
   value one by one:

   ```
            var ModelObject = $('#form').serializeArray();
            for (var i = 0; i < ModelObject.length; i++) {
             fdata.append(ModelObject[i].name, ModelObject[i].value);
            }
   ```

Here is complete code:

Model:

```
public class UploadVm 
    { 
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(IFormFile files, UploadVm model)
    {
        return View();

    }
```

View:

```
      <form id="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            ID:<input type="text" name="ID" id="id" /><br>
            Name:<input type="text" name="Name" id="name" /><br>
            File:<input type="file" id="postedFile" /><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="upload" value="Submit" />
        </form>


@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $("#upload").click(function (e) {

            event.preventDefault();
            var files = $("#postedFile").get(0).files;
            var fdata = new FormData($('#form').get(0));//the first way
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                fdata.append("files", files[i]);
            };
            
            //the second way 
            //var ModelObject = $('#form').serializeArray(); 
            //for (var i = 0; i < ModelObject.length; i++) {
            //    fdata.append(ModelObject[i].name, ModelObject[i].value);
            //}

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/Index',
                data: fdata,
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                type: 'POST',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, error) {
                    alert("error!");
                }
            });
        }); 
    </script> 
}
```

You can also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc).

Here is the test result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try like below.

- Remove `dataType: "json",`, `async: false,`.
- Update your `fdata` and `append` serializeObject, like `fdata.append("model", ModelObject);`.
- Make sure your `parameter` names in `action` must match with `files` and `model`. These are the names you used with `fdata.append`.

Complete code will look like below.

```
//Step 1: All uploaded files
var files = $("#postedFile").get(0).files;
var fdata = new FormData();
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  fdata.append("files", files[i]);
};

//Step 2: Serialized form 
var ModelObject = $('#form').serializeObject();
fdata.append("model", ModelObject);

//Step 3: Ajax call:
$.ajax({
  url: '/controller/actionname',
  data: fdata,
  type: 'post',
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  },
  error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, error) {
    emailStatus = false;
  }
});
```